# My KeyListener doesn't respond to my JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, tetris

I'm writing a Tetris game and most of my mechanism is done. I tried to input my keyboard interaction creating a new KeyListener, but it simply doesn't seem to work, as I press the buttons the pieces just keep falling instead of changing their position. Could anybody help me please?

GUI Class:

```
package tetris;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Game extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Library obj = new Library();

public Game() {
    initComponents();

    jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(15,20));
    for(int i = 0; i<15; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<20; j++){
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setSize(15, 15);
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("whitetile.png")));
            jPanel1.add(label);
            obj.setTiles(i, j, label);
            label.addKeyListener(new KeyListener());
            this.setFocusable(true);
            this.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
    obj.start();
}

private class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter{

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt){
        if(evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            obj.tiles[obj.r1][obj.col1].setIcon(obj.white);
            obj.tiles[obj.r2][obj.col2].setIcon(obj.white);
            obj.tiles[obj.r3][obj.col3].setIcon(obj.white);
            obj.tiles[obj.r4][obj.col4].setIcon(obj.white);
            obj.col1 -= 1;
            obj.col2 -= 1;
            obj.col3 -= 1;
            obj.col4 -= 1;

            obj.tiles[obj.r1][obj.col1].setIcon(obj.red);
            obj.tiles[obj.r2][obj.col2].setIcon(obj.red);
            obj.tiles[obj.r3][obj.col3].setIcon(obj.red);
            obj.tiles[obj.r4][obj.col4].setIcon(obj.red);
        }

        if(evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            obj.tiles[obj.r1][obj.col1].setIcon(obj.white);
            obj.tiles[obj.r2][obj.col2].setIcon(obj.white);
            obj.tiles[obj.r3][obj.col3].setIcon(obj.white);
            obj.tiles[obj.r4][obj.col4].setIcon(obj.white);
            obj.col1 += 1;
            obj.col2 += 1;
            obj.col3 += 1;
            obj.col4 += 1;

            obj.tiles[obj.r1][obj.col1].setIcon(obj.red);
            obj.tiles[obj.r2][obj.col2].setIcon(obj.red);
            obj.tiles[obj.r3][obj.col3].setIcon(obj.red);
            obj.tiles[obj.r4][obj.col4].setIcon(obj.red);
        }

        if(evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            obj.spin();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt){

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt){

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 225));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 350, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 338, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Nivel: " + String.valueOf(obj.level));

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Puntuacion: " + String.valueOf(obj.score));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 102, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 102, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(81, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 338, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(118, 118, 118)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(40, 40, 40)
            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
    * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
    */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Game().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Library class:

```
package tetris;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Library extends Thread{
JLabel tiles[][] = new JLabel[15][20];
ImageIcon red = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redtile.png"));
ImageIcon white = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("whitetile.png"));
char figset = ' ';
int score = 0;
int level = 1;
int col1 = -1, col2 = -1, col3 = -1, col4 = -1, r1 = -1, r2 = -1, r3 = -1, r4 = -1;
int fallrate = 1500;

public void play(){
    Timer tm = new Timer();
    tm.start();
    boolean isPlaying = true;

    while(isPlaying){
        boolean isFalling = true;
        int tspinned = 0;
        setFigure();

        while(isFalling){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(fallrate);

                tiles[r1][col1].setIcon(white);
                tiles[r2][col2].setIcon(white);
                tiles[r3][col3].setIcon(white);
                tiles[r4][col4].setIcon(white);
                r1 += 1;
                r2 += 1;
                r3 += 1;
                r4 += 1;

                tiles[r1][col1].setIcon(red);
                tiles[r2][col2].setIcon(red);
                tiles[r3][col3].setIcon(red);
                tiles[r4][col4].setIcon(red);

                if((r1 == tiles.length-1 || r2 == tiles.length-1 || r3 == tiles.length-1 || r4 == tiles.length-1) ||
                        (tiles[r1+1][col1].getIcon() == red&&r1+1 != r2 && r1+1 != r3 && r1+1 != r4) || (tiles[r2+1][col2].getIcon() == red&&r2+1 != r1 && r2+1 != r3 && r2+1 != r4) ||
                        (tiles[r3+1][col3].getIcon() == red&&r3+1 != r2 && r3+1 != r1 && r3+1 != r4) || (tiles[r4+1][col4].getIcon() == red&&r4+1 != r2 && r4+1 != r3 && r4+1 != r1)){
                    isFalling = false;
                    checkwin(r1,r2,r3,r4);
                    if(r1+1 == 2 || r2+1 == 2 || r3+1 == 2 || r4+1 == 2){
                        isPlaying = false;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Library.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ha perdido.\nPuntuación final: " + score);
    System.exit(0);
}

public void spin(){

}

public void setTiles(int row, int col, JLabel label){
    tiles[row][col] = label;
}

public void setFigure(){
    int choice = (int)(Math.random()*7)+1;      

    switch(choice){
        case 1: //I block
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
                tiles[i][9].setIcon(red);
            }
            col1 = 9;
            col2 = 9;
            col3 = 9;
            col4 = 9;
            r1 = 0;
            r2 = 1;
            r3 = 2;
            r4 = 3;
            figset = 'I';
            break;
        case 2: //J block
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                tiles[i][9].setIcon(red);
            }
            tiles[2][8].setIcon(red);
            col1 = 9;
            col2 = 9;
            col3 = 9;
            col4 = 8;
            r1 = 0;
            r2 = 1;
            r3 = 2;
            r4 = 2;
            figset = 'J';
            break;
        case 3: //L block
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                tiles[i][9].setIcon(red);
            }
            tiles[2][10].setIcon(red);
            col1 = 9;
            col2 = 9;
            col3 = 9;
            col4 = 10;
            r1 = 0;
            r2 = 1;
            r3 = 2;
            r4 = 2;
            figset = 'L';
            break;
        case 4: //O block
            for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
                for(int j = 8; j<10; j++){
                    tiles[i][j].setIcon(red);
                }
            }
            col1 = 9;
            col2 = 9;
            col3 = 10;
            col4 = 10;
            r1 = 0;
            r2 = 1;
            r3 = 0;
            r4 = 1;
            figset = 'O';
            break;
        case 5: //S block
            for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
                tiles[i][9].setIcon(red);
            }
            tiles[0][10].setIcon(red);
            tiles[1][8].setIcon(red);
            col1 = 9;
            col2 = 9;
            col3 = 10;
            col4 = 8;
            r1 = 0;
            r2 = 1;
            r3 = 0;
            r4 = 1;
            figset = 'S';
            break;
        case 6: //Z block
            for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
                tiles[i][9].setIcon(red);
            }
            tiles[0][8].setIcon(red);
            tiles[1][10].setIcon(red);
            col1 = 9;
            col2 = 9;
            col3 = 10;
            col4 = 8;
            r1 = 0;
            r2 = 1;
            r3 = 1;
            r4 = 0;
            figset = 'Z';
            break;
        case 7: //T block
            for(int i = 8; i<11; i++){
                tiles[0][i].setIcon(red);
            }
            tiles[1][9].setIcon(red);
            col1 = 8;
            col2 = 9;
            col3 = 10;
            col4 = 9;
            r1 = 0;
            r2 = 0;
            r3 = 0;
            r4 = 1;
            figset = 'T';
            break;
    }
}

public void checkwin(int one, int two, int three, int four){
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<tiles[0].length; i++){
        if(tiles[one][i].getIcon() == red){
            c++;
        }
    }
    if(c == tiles[0].length){
        for(int i = 0; i<tiles[0].length; i++){
            tiles[one][i].setIcon(white);
        }
        score += 1000;

    }

    c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<tiles[0].length; i++){
        if(tiles[two][i].getIcon() == red){
            c++;
        }
    }
    if(c == tiles[0].length){
        for(int i = 0; i<tiles[0].length; i++){
            tiles[two][i].setIcon(white);
        }
        score += 1000;
    }


    c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<tiles[0].length; i++){
        if(tiles[three][i].getIcon() == red){
            c++;
        }
    }
    if(c == tiles[0].length){
        for(int i = 0; i<tiles[0].length; i++){
            tiles[three][i].setIcon(white);
        }
        score += 1000;
    }

    c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<tiles[0].length; i++){
        if(tiles[four][i].getIcon() == red){
            c++;
        }
    }
    if(c == tiles[0].length){
        for(int i = 0; i<tiles[0].length; i++){
            tiles[four][i].setIcon(white);
        }
        score += 1000;
    }
}

public void run(){
    play();
}
}
```

Comment: As has been discussed many times, don't use KeyListener for this, but instead Key Bindings. Please see my answer for a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21867339/522444).

Comment: And also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21817447/522444).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component they registered to has key board focus AND is focusable.

`JLabel` is not focusable by default.

Now, there are things you can "try" to make this work, or you could just use the a [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which was designed to fix these issues

Comment: So, after focusing the jLabel, should I put the KeyBinding instead of adding a Keylistener?

Comment: You should simply use the key bindings API. Key bindings allow you to overcome the focusing issues. I'd simply apply the bindings to parent container, personally