# ActionListener class keeps repeating when swing Timer is started

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to develop a very basic "Simon says" simulator using Java GUI. I have a method that generates and returns an `int[]` array; for each element in the array, the Timer `computer` should start, call the `doClick()` method for the specified `JButton`, and wait for 1/2 a second. Each `JButton` is connected to an `ActionListener()` that changes the color of the specific button to white, activates another Timer `timer`, and changes the button back to its original color.

Every time I call `computer.start();` within the for-loop it runs the code within `ComputerListener()`, but it repeats endlessly. I have added print statements so that I can see what is going on via the output on Netbeans. I have looked at similar issues on the forum, but nothing has provided a viable solution.

My question: why is my `ComputerListener` class repeating when `computer.start();` is called within the for-loop?

```
package simon;

// @jagged_prospect

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;

public class SIMONPanel extends JPanel{

private static final int PANEL_W=300,PANEL_H=300;
private static final int PREF_W=500,PREF_H=500;
private static final String[] CARD_LABELS={"main","info","game"};

private final JPanel gameCard,infoCard,splashCard;
private final JButton rButton,yButton,gButton,bButton;
private final int lives=3;

private CardLayout cardlayout=new CardLayout();
private JPanel cards=new JPanel(cardlayout);
private Action[] actions={new ShowMainAction(),new ShowInfoAction(),
    new ShowGameAction()};
private Object source;
private Timer timer,computer;

public SIMONPanel(){
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    gameCard=new JPanel();
    infoCard=new JPanel();
    splashCard=new JPanel();

    // game card panel
    gameCard.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    gameCard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_W,PANEL_H));

    JPanel gameButtonPanel=new JPanel();
    gameButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    JButton startButton=new JButton("Start");
    startButton.addActionListener(new StartListener());

    rButton=new JButton("red");
    rButton.addActionListener(new ColorButtonListener());
    rButton.setSize(50,50);
    rButton.setUI((ButtonUI)BasicButtonUI.createUI(rButton));
    rButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
    rButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    yButton=new JButton("yellow");
    yButton.addActionListener(new ColorButtonListener());
    yButton.setSize(50,50);
    yButton.setUI((ButtonUI)BasicButtonUI.createUI(yButton));
    yButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    gButton=new JButton("green");
    gButton.addActionListener(new ColorButtonListener());
    gButton.setSize(50,50);
    gButton.setUI((ButtonUI)BasicButtonUI.createUI(gButton));
    gButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    bButton=new JButton("blue");
    bButton.addActionListener(new ColorButtonListener());
    bButton.setSize(50,50);
    bButton.setUI((ButtonUI)BasicButtonUI.createUI(bButton));
    bButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    bButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    gameButtonPanel.add(gButton);
    gameButtonPanel.add(rButton);
    gameButtonPanel.add(yButton);
    gameButtonPanel.add(bButton); 
    gameCard.add(gameButtonPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    gameCard.add(startButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // splash card panel
    splashCard.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    splashCard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_W,PANEL_H));
    splashCard.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JLabel titleLabel=new JLabel("S I M O N",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Niagara Solid",Font.BOLD,84));
    titleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    splashCard.add(titleLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // info card panel
    // nothing here yet

    JPanel buttonPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,5,0));
    for(Action action : actions){
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(action));
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    cards.add(splashCard,CARD_LABELS[0]);
    cards.add(infoCard,CARD_LABELS[1]);
    cards.add(gameCard,CARD_LABELS[2]);

    add(cards,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
// sets uniform panel size
    @Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
}
// shows the Main Menu card
private class ShowMainAction extends AbstractAction {
    public ShowMainAction() {
        super("Main");
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cardlayout.show(cards,CARD_LABELS[0]);
    } 
}
// shows the Info card
private class ShowInfoAction extends AbstractAction {
    public ShowInfoAction() {
        super("Info");
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cardlayout.show(cards,CARD_LABELS[1]);
    }
}
// show the Game card
private class ShowGameAction extends AbstractAction {
    public ShowGameAction() {
        super("Game");
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cardlayout.show(cards,CARD_LABELS[2]);
    }
}
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(source==gButton){
            gButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else if(source==rButton){
            rButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
            rButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        else if(source==yButton){
            yButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        else if(source==bButton){
            bButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            bButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        } 
    }
}
private class ColorButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        source=event.getSource();
        int delay=300;
        timer=new Timer(delay,new TimerListener());

        if(source==gButton){
            gButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }
        else if(source==rButton){
            rButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            rButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }
        else if(source==yButton){
            yButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }
        else if(source==bButton){
            bButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            bButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }     
    }
}
private class StartListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        // calls generateSequence() to make pattern for player to replicate
        // for debugging in output
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateSequence()));
    }
}
public int[] generateSequence(){
    Random ran=new Random();
    ComputerListener cpu=new ComputerListener();
    computer=new javax.swing.Timer(500,cpu);
    int seqLen=4;
    int[] gameSequence=new int[seqLen];
    for(int x=0;x<seqLen;x++){
       int assign=ran.nextInt(4)+1;
       gameSequence[x]=assign;
    }
    for(int y=0;y<seqLen;y++){ // print and wait 1/2 second, repeat 3 times
        computer.start();
    }
    //computer.stop(); // should stop ComputerListener()???
    return gameSequence;
}
private class ComputerListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        // for debugging in output
        System.out.println("it worked");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the computer Swing Timer's start button multiple times in a for loop, and that is *not* what you want to do, and in fact, the whole purpose of the timer is to help you *get rid of the for loop*. Instead the Timer repeats an action, and changes a state, and keeps going until its done. Consider using an int array or better an ArrayList to hold the colors that the timer should iterate through, and within that ActionListener, do the action and advance a pointer to the next position in the array or List, using that pointer to decide what action to do next. Then when the pointer is completely through the collection, stop the Timer.

For an example of *exactly* what I'm describing, please check out my Timer's ActionListener for an incomplete Simon game here: [Method keeps window from closing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21867339/522444)

The Timer's ActionListener, annotated, is below:

```
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    private SimonPanel simonPanel;  // the Simon JPanel
    private int colorListIndex = 0; // index into the ArrayList of MyColor objects
    private int sliceCount = 0;
    private List<MyColor> myColorList; // the MyColor ArrayList -- the random colors to press
    private int maxCount;

    public TimerListener(SimonPanel simonPanel, List<MyColor> myColorList) {
        // pass in the key fields into the program via constructor parameter
        this.simonPanel = simonPanel;
        this.myColorList = myColorList;  // again the ArrayList that holds random MyColor objects
        maxCount = myColorList.size();  // size of my list
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // if index at the end of the list -- get out and clean up
        if (colorListIndex == maxCount) {
            // clear the display of "pressed" colors
            for (MyColor myColor : MyColor.values()) {
                simonPanel.setMyColorPressed(myColor, false);
            }

            // stop this timer
            ((Timer) evt.getSource()).stop();
            return;
        }

        // the listener is a little complex since it must turn on colors and turn them off 
        // which is why I use a sliceCount int counter variable here
        if (sliceCount == 0) {
            // turn on the next color in the list (using the index)
            MyColor myColor = myColorList.get(colorListIndex);
            simonPanel.setMyColorPressed(myColor, true);
            sliceCount++;
        } else if (sliceCount < TIME_SLICES - 1) {
            sliceCount++;
            return;
        } else if (sliceCount == TIME_SLICES - 1) {
            sliceCount = 0;
            MyColor myColor = myColorList.get(colorListIndex);
            simonPanel.setMyColorPressed(myColor, false);  // turn off the color 
            colorListIndex++;  // and increment the index
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for two answers that give the same advice.

Comment: I'm just beginning to really use GUI, and Timer objects are new to me. Your solutions have helped substantially. Much thanks.